# Add ArrayList of unknown length to XML file

Tags: java, jaxb

I'm using JAXB to save my candidates tableview in to an XML.

Here's the current output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<candidates>
    <person>
        <name>A</name>
        <weight>100</weight>
    </person>
    <person>
        <name>B</name>
        <weight>120</weight>
    </person>
</candidates>
```

Here's my file saving method:

```
public void savePerToFile(File file) {
        try {
            JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(PerListWrapper.class);
            Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
            m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
            PerListWrapper wrapper = new PerListWrapper();
            wrapper.person(perData);
            m.marshal(wrapper, file);
            }
    }
```

The data comes from an observable list:

```
private ObservableList<Person> perData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
```

My person wrapper class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "candidates")
public class PerListWrapper {

    private List<Person> candidates;

    public PerListWrapper() {
        candidates = FXCollections.<Person>observableArrayList();
    }

    public void setPerson(List<Person> candidates) {
        this.candidates = candidates;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "person")
    public List<Person> getPerson() {
        return this.candidates;
    }
}
```

Now I want to be able to add daily weight tracking data from an array list to my XML. All candidates have matching test days. So the output should look something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<candidates>
    <person>
        <name>A</name>
        <weight>100</weight>
            <tests>
                <num>1</num>
                    <date>2014-04-25</date>
                    <weight>99</weight>
                <num>2</num>
                    <date>2014-04-26</date>
                    <weight>98</weight>
                <num>3</num>
                    <date>2014-04-27</date>
                    <weight>99</weight>
            <tests>
    </person>
    <person>
        <name>B</name>
        <weight>120</weight>
            <tests>
                <num>1</num>
                    <date>2014-04-25</date>
                    <weight>122</weight>
                <num>2</num>
                    <date>2014-04-26</date>
                    <weight>121</weight>
                <num>3</num>
                    <date>2014-04-27</date>
                    <weight>120</weight>
            <tests>
    </person>
</candidates>
```

Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That really seems like "the wrong way to do it". Better: `<tests><test><num>1</num><date>2014-04-27</date><weight>122</weight></test> <!-- ... --></tests>`

Comment: thanks beerbajay. i've updated the look of my desired output. will I have to work with child elements?

Comment: Yes, you need child `<test>` elements. You shouldn't have to do anything especially difficult besides annotate your `Person` and `Test` classes, where `Person` should have a `List<Test>`.